# What is Golden Ratio and how do we implement it in designs?

Tags: user-centered-design

What is Golden Ratio? how do we use it during interface designing?

Comment: [Mashable article](http://mashable.com/2010/09/29/new-twitter-golden-ratio/#eMoW4sgXi8qy) showing golden ratio used for 'new' twitter design in 2010. Also this answer on [Usage of Golden Ratio](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11479/usage-of-golden-ratio)

Answer (score 3):

The golden ratio (or golden sectio as it is often called), is **1.6180339**...

You can read about its history, the usage in painting, architecture etc on [wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

A good article about how to apply it in UI layouts can be found [here](http://uxmovement.com/content/applying-the-golden-ratio-to-layouts-and-rectangles/).

Answer (score 0):

**Rule of thirds**

> One of the first lesson photographers learn is about the Rule of
>   thirds. A simpler way to understand golden rule.

It defines a rule of thumb compose a shot(for photographers) and to keep the content balanced and interesting for the **viewer**. (Sounds familiar!! :))

[This Tutorial](http://digital-photography-school.com/rule-of-thirds) from Digital Photography school on this is a very useful one to understand the basics of composition.

The same can be extended to different fields including art, design etc. The overarching goal is to compose the content around the points of interest defined by the rule of thirds/golden rule.

[image]

[image]

[Check out this tutorial by Tutsplus](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/making-your-web-designs-more-effective-with-the-golden-ratio--cms-23459) on applying the rule to web design.

Comment: The rule of thirds is not the same as the Golden Ratio.

Comment: @JonW My intentional was not to equate golden rule to rule of thirds, but the principle. The idea of leading the user/viewer to the content is easier to understand via rule of thirds. End of day, Rule of thirds, Golden Rule, Golden Triangles intend to do the same.

Comment: That is as may-be, but the question itself was very specific to the Golden ratio. If people search this site for Golden ratio and found your answer then they may mistakenly assume that the Rule of 3rds *is* the golden ratio. Which is incorrect. I'm not suggesting your answer is of no use, just that it is incorrect for this question.